# Is it possible to write to a DynamoDB Global Secondary Index?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

For example, would it possible to put or update an item using the Global Secondary Index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no - it's not possible to put or update an item using an index.

But this is a really interesting question and I think it helps to think about why it is not possible. First, an index is a projection of the source data, and the index is not necessarily a bijection between the original data set and the projected set. Said differently, the index could contain duplicates records, so how would you handle that for writes? I suppose you could make an argument that the system could do a bulk update for all source records but that is not always correct.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the answer! Your explanation makes since, though is there any reference to this in the DynamoDB docs?

Comment: Good question - unfortunately I couldn't find a reference in the docs. But you can't to prove a negative, so I can't say with 100% certainty that there is no mention of this in the docs anywhere.